# my math is broken on TextView

Tags: java, android

To be honest I've just started with programming but for the life of me I can't figure out where I'm wrong.

the math is:
10$ / 2 hours

tips per hour = 5 (i get 0.2)

waiter 1 pay = 10 (i get 0.4?)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKDjQ.png)

The Calculation in MainActivity:

```
double resultTotalHours = cWaiter1Hours + cWaiter2Hours + cWaiter3Hours + cWaiter4Hours;
            double calcTipsPerHour = resultTotalHours / totalTips;
            double resultBarsCut = (totalTips * (cBarCutInput / 100));
            double resultTaxDeposit = resultTotalHours * 3;
            double resultTipsPerHour = (totalTips - resultBarsCut - resultTaxDeposit) / resultTotalHours;

            double resultWaiter1Pay = cWaiter1Hours * resultTipsPerHour;
            double resultWaiter2Pay = cWaiter2Hours * resultTipsPerHour;
            double resultWaiter3Pay = cWaiter3Hours * resultTipsPerHour;
            double resultWaiter4Pay = cWaiter4Hours * resultTipsPerHour;

            double resultWaiter1NoTax = cWaiter1Hours * calcTipsPerHour;
            double resultWaiter2NoTax = cWaiter2Hours * calcTipsPerHour;
            double resultWaiter3NoTax = cWaiter3Hours * calcTipsPerHour;
            double resultWaiter4NoTax = cWaiter4Hours * calcTipsPerHour;
```

Casting the results to the TextViews:

```
if (calcTipsPerHour <= 30) {

                totalHoursView.setText(Double.toString(resultTotalHours));
                tipsPerHourView.setText(Double.toString(calcTipsPerHour));
                barsCutView.setText(Double.toString(0));
                taxDepositView.setText(Double.toString(0));

                waiter1Pay.setText(Double.toString(resultWaiter1NoTax));
                waiter2Pay.setText(Double.toString(resultWaiter2NoTax));
                waiter3Pay.setText(Double.toString(resultWaiter3NoTax));
                waiter4Pay.setText(Double.toString(resultWaiter4NoTax));

            } else {

                totalHoursView.setText(Double.toString(resultTotalHours));
                tipsPerHourView.setText(Double.toString(resultTipsPerHour));
                barsCutView.setText(Double.toString(resultBarsCut));
                taxDepositView.setText(Double.toString(resultTaxDeposit));

                waiter1Pay.setText(Double.toString(resultWaiter1Pay));
                waiter2Pay.setText(Double.toString(resultWaiter2Pay));
                waiter3Pay.setText(Double.toString(resultWaiter3Pay));
                waiter4Pay.setText(Double.toString(resultWaiter4Pay));




            }
```

Comment: Can you please try to create a [mcve]? Not sure what your screenshot shows...

Comment: edited. sorry about that.

Comment: `calcTipsPerHour = resultTotalHours / totalTips` Why do you calc 2/10 and not 10/2 like you said you want to? Voted to close as typo.

Comment: No, such edits aren't welcome. Don't edit the answer into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
double calcTipsPerHour = resultTotalHours / totalTips;
```

This is currently doing 2 / 10 = 0.2.

You want to do the reciprocal:

```
double calcTipsPerHour = totalTips / resultTotalHours;
```

This should also fix your waiter's pay

Answer (score 0):

You put hours in the numerator and tips in the denominator so you are getting the inverse of what you want: hours/tip

What you want is:

```
double calcTipsPerHour = totalTips / resultTotalHours;
```